# How to repeat individual characters in strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I know that

```
"123abc" * 2
```

evaluates as `"123abc123abc"`, but is there an easy way to repeat individual letters N times, e.g. convert `"123abc"` to `"112233aabbcc"` or `"111222333aaabbbccc"`?

Comment: Try using a for loop and concatenate chars to get desired output.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What about:

```
>>> s = '123abc'
>>> n = 3
>>> ''.join([char*n for char in s])
'111222333aaabbbccc'
>>>
```

(changed to a list comp from a generator expression as using a list comp inside join is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2302482))

Comment: ah,  I like using comprehensions, I was having a brain cramp for some reason.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to repeat *individual* letters you can just replace the letter with n letters e.g.

```
>>> s = 'abcde'
>>> s.replace('b', 'b'*5, 1)
'abbbbbcde'
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)-problem-overcomplicating-style option with `repeat()`, `izip()` and `chain()`:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, izip, chain
>>> "".join(chain(*izip(*repeat(s, 2))))
'112233aabbcc'
>>> "".join(chain(*izip(*repeat(s, 3))))
'111222333aaabbbccc'
```

Or, "I know regexes and I'll use it for everything"-style option:

```
>>> import re
>>> n = 2
>>> re.sub(".", lambda x: x.group() * n, s)  # or re.sub('(.)', r'\1' * n, s) - thanks Eduardo
'112233aabbcc'
```

Of course, don't use these solutions in practice.

Answer (score 6):

Or another way to do it would be using `map`:

```
"".join(map(lambda x: x*7, "map"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123abc'
>>> n = 3
>>> re.sub('(.)', r'\1' * n, s)
'111222333aaabbbccc'
```

Answer (score 2):

And since I use numpy for everything, here we go:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
''.join(np.array(list(st*n)).reshape(n, -1).T.ravel())
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my naive solution

```
text = "123abc"
result = ''
for letters in text:
    result += letters*3

print(result)
```

output:
111222333aaabbbccc

Answer (score 1):

@Bahrom's answer is probably clearer than mine, but just to say that there are many solutions to this problem:

```
>>> s = '123abc'
>>> n = 3
>>> reduce(lambda s0, c: s0 + c*n, s, "")
'111222333aaabbbccc'
```

Note that `reduce` is not a built-in in python 3, and you have to use `functools.reduce` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def letter_repeater(n, string):
    word = ''
    for char in list(string):
        word += char * n
    print word

letter_repeater(4, 'monkeys')


mmmmoooonnnnkkkkeeeeyyyyssss
```

Comment: yeah, that's the obvious imperative way, I figured there was something more Pythonic though. (I'd recommend `return word` rather than `print word` by the way)

Comment: @JasonS, I think the other options given are more pythonic, but it gets the job done. And agreed on the `return` vs. `print`, just thought it would be quicker to get the point across

Comment: p.s. you also don't need to use `list(string)` -- strings are iterable already. (And I did upvote you btw!)

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
def  LetterRepeater(times,word) :
    word1=''
    for letters in word:
        word1 += letters * times
    print(word1)

    word=input('Write down the word :   ')
    times=int(input('How many times you want to replicate the letters ?    '))
    LetterRepeater(times,word)
```

Comment: Welcome. It looks like this needs some additional care in terms of the indentation—and especially since this is python. Can you edit it? Also, as this question already has nine other answers—including [an accepted answer with 34 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38273369/3025856)—please be sure to explain how your approach differs from existing approaches, and why your approach might be preferred.