# Not able to multiply letters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Question is:

PAPER DOLL: Given a string, return a string where for every character in the original there are three characters:

```
paper_doll('Hello') --> 'HHHeeellllllooo'
paper_doll('Mississippi') --> 'MMMiiissssssiiippppppiii'
```

and I wrote the code:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    for lettes in text:
        for i in range(0, len(text) - 1):
            return text[i] * 3
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273353/how-to-repeat-individual-characters-in-strings-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, this function will take every letter from the given text, triple it and return the new string :

```
def paper_doll(text):
    out = []
    for letter in text:
        out.append(letter*3)
    return ''.join(out)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a few mistakes in your script

One is your for loop is outside of the definition, Second is you don't call your function.

```
def paper_doll(text):
for lettes in text:
    for i in range(0,len(text)-1):
        return text[i]*3
```

Try this one:

```
text="hello"
newtext2=""

def paper_doll(text,newtext2):

    for letter in text:
        newtext = str( letter* 3)
        newtext2+=newtext

    print(newtext2)


paper_doll(text,newtext2)
```

Answer (score -2):

there are a few reasons why your code won't work as you intend to:

1. you are returning the output instead of printing it
2. your code is running through an extra loop which is unnecessary

this would do the job:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    for letter in text:
        print(letter * 3, end="")
```