# do you know how to duplicate several times each word in a text file using python?

Tags: python

i have a txt file with several words on it, does anybody know how to duplicate each word two times as the next example

hello
bye

---

hello

hello

hello

bye

bye

bye

regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat individual characters in strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273353/how-to-repeat-individual-characters-in-strings-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To avoid your question getting downvoted, you should show what attempts you have made so far, and why those attempts don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, but for sure there are better solutions:

```
text ="hello bye"
text_out = []
times_to_duplicate = 3
for word in text.split(" "):
    for i in range(times_to_duplicate + 1):
        text_out.append(word)

" ".join(text_out)
```

Or as list comprehention, as @Sushanth states:

```
"".join(f"{x} " * 3 for x in "hello bye".split())
```

I would recommend you, before asking a question to check the grammar and punctuation to improve the quality of your question

Comment: ``range`` is redundant here, ``"".join(f"{x} " * 3 for x in "hello bye".split())``

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: Thanks this is great

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can replicate a string by multiplying the string n number of times.

example: this will repeat hello 3 times

```
>>> 'hello' * 3
'hellohellohello'
```

If you want a space between that, then you can do it as follows:

```
>>> 'hello ' * 3
'hello hello hello '
```

Using this as your base, you can write the code as follows to get the desired result.

```
txt = 'hello bye'
#now split the word and iterate thru each word by creating a new list
txt1 = [(t+' ')*3 for t in txt.split(' ')]

#you now have a new list txt1 with repeated words
#if you want it as a single string, you need to concatenate that using join

txt2 = ' '.join(txt1)

print (txt2)
```