# How to double the strings in Python ex. "Hello" to "HHeelllloo"

Tags: python, slice, notation

how do I do this with sliced notation?

ex. "Hello" to "HHeelloo"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat individual characters in strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273353/how-to-repeat-individual-characters-in-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term slicing in programming usually refers to obtaining a substring, sub-tuple, or sublist from a string, tuple, or list respectively. You cannot slice a string to double every character. Though you can use sliced notation- method 6. Here are some methods to get the desirable output.

Method 1:

```
input = Hello
output=""
for i in input:
    output = output + i*2
print(output)
```

Method 2:

```
"".join(2 * i for i in "Hello")
```

Method 3:

```
s='Hello'
from itertools import chain,izip
''.join(chain(*izip(s,s)))
```

Method 4:

```
s.translate({ord(x):2*x for x in set(s)})
```

Method 5:

```
s = "Hello"
import re
re.sub('(.)', r'\1' * 2, s)
```

Method 6 (using sliced notation):

```
s = "Hello"
s1 = 2 * s
s2 = ""
for i in range(len(s)):
    s2 += s1[i::len(s)]
print(s2)
```

All would result in:

```
HHeelllloo
```

Comment: I suggest you credit and upvote the answers you copy content from.

Comment: For the answer 6, I take reference from some answers on the internet and yours too! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the input string, then use the multiplication operator to duplicate the string and then concatenate again using `join()`:

```
"".join(2 * s for s in "Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop each letter in your string and add it twice to a new string. For example

```
word = "Hello"
doubledWord = ""
for letter in word:
    doubledWord += letter * 2

print(doubledWord)
```

Output

```
HHeelllloo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join function and for loop to an empty string. The letters will be double of all letters.

```
s="Hello"
"".join([x*2 for x in s])
```

Comment: I am just starting a course fundamentals in Python and we haven't yet reached functions of this kind. I would like to understand how to do this with slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Word = 'Hello'
number_of_time = 2
''.join([char*number_of_time for char in Word])
```

Output:

```
'HHeelllloo'
```

Comment: Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273353/how-to-repeat-individual-characters-in-strings-in-python

Comment: The question should just be flagged as a duplicated of that link.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by iterating the whole string and at each iteration multiply the string by 2

```
str1 = 'Hello'
str2= ''
for i in range(len(str1)):

    str2 += str1[i]*2

print(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sliced notation in a non-trivial manner:

```
s = "Sajad"
s2 = 2 * "Sajad"
ss = ""
for i in range(len(s)):
    ss += s2[i::len(s)]
print(ss)
```